# Does all single threaded software run on the main core/thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, ubuntu, single-threaded

I'm planning to run for example 10 instances of a single software - single-threaded game server.
They will run on a server machine(not VPS) on plain Linux Ubuntu(console version).

My question is, if I do this, all the load will be on the main thread? or each instance will take his own thread.

Comment: The short answer is no. Assuming no specific processor pinning (e.g with cgroups) the kernel will decide which processor each process/thread will run on at any given time.

Comment: There is no such thing as "main core" for applications running under a typical OS running on a typical desktop, mobile, or generic server-type host. The hardware and software of such systems implement _[symmetric multiprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing) (SMP),_ in which all of the CPUs are peers. I don't know much about SMP operating system internals. Probably one CPU plays a special role during boot, and it _might_ continue to have some special role within the kernel code, but if so, it's entirely hidden from user-mode application programs.

Comment: When programmers say, "main thread," they usually are talking about the _first_ thread to start running within any given application program. But normally the main thread of a program is not constrained to run on (a.k.a., "has no _affinity_ for") any particular CPU. In fact, the main thread of long-running program quite likely will be moved from CPU to CPU by the operating system during the process lifetime if other processes and threads compe with it for system resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thread always belongs to a process, so if you have 10 instances of a software running on 10 processes they will run on the main thread of each process. Then the processor will assign each thread to an specific core depending on the available resources

Comment: So if I have 4 or more cores on my CPU, the system will use all of them and not the only main core?

Comment: Yes, probably, but don’t forget that you can't control explicitly the use of cores of your CPU, this is a linux kernel job